# How to run php on front page or home page only?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below which I'm using to show categories only. 
The problem I'm facing is it shows categories list on all pages.
I want to use this piece of code on front page or home page only.
How can I show categories list on front page/home page only?

I only have knowledge of html and css, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks and Regards.

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'list_categories' );
function list_categories() {

echo '<div class="archive-description">';

wp_list_categories(
array(
'title_li' => '') 
 );

echo '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test if page [is home](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_home/) or [front page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/):

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'list_categories' );
function list_categories() {
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
        echo '<div class="archive-description">';
        wp_list_categories(['title_li' => '']);            
        echo '</div>';        
    }
}
```